# How do I generate a Fibonacci series in Python whose value shouldn't exceed a target value

Tags: python, function, fibonacci

New to Python and need some help.

I'm trying to generate a Fibonacci series and push each element into a list. I'd like to set a condition such that I do not want the Fibonacci list to include any element larger than a target value. I created a function myFib to generate this list and pass an argument of 20 hoping that my Fibonacci list only contains values less than 20. My loop stops after it appends the element 21 and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Once I get this to work, I want to do it for a target value of 2000000 so trying to figure out mechanic before I set a large target value. Appreciate any help.

```
def myFib(max_count):
    a = 1
    b = 1
    fiblist = [1, 1]
    while fiblist[-1] <= max_count:
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp + a
        fiblist.append(b)
        print(fiblist)
    return fiblist

myFib(20)
```

Output I'm getting is

[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition in your code that break the `while` loop in order to not have any value that exceeds your `max_count` variable, like this example:

```
def myFib(max_count):
    a = 1
    b = 1
    fiblist = [1, 1]
    while fiblist[-1] <= max_count:
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp + a
        if b > max_count:
            break
        fiblist.append(b)
        # print(fiblist)
    return fiblist
```

Output:

```
myFib(20)
>>> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```